# How should I add JQuery on custom page layout for SP2013?

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-layout, publishing-page

I am working on a SP2013 on-premise farm and try to create a custom page layout. There are some JQuery function I need it render on particular custom page layout but not other pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[  
        hangCurrentURLBreadcrumb("path-breadcrumb-prefix");
//]]>
</script>
```

I added above snippet to my custom page layout html. It doesn't renderat all. However when I added it to the same location of my custom Master page, it works.

May I know what is the suggested way to add JS or JQuery to custom layout page? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom page layout first add path to .js file (put path to `src=""`)
and then code.

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js">//<![CDATA[
//]]>
</script>

<script>//<![CDATA[

            $(document).ready(function(){
            //some code         
            });

//]]>
</script>
<!--MS:<Publishing:EditModePanel runat="server" id="editmodestyles">-->
...
```

Place it just above the Publishing:EditModePanel tag

Comment: Oh! It works now. The only change I made is moving the snippet above Publishing:EditModePanel tag. Why it makes the different?

Comment: It must be before all that publishing registration for jquery to work. Please mark as answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add your scripts in the following section too.

```
 <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" 
      AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI,

If you are only after using (simple) jQuery selectors.

Microsoft has this thing called mQuery built in SharePoint.

So jQuerys:

```
$('#myID')
```

becomes:

```
m$('myID')
```

**straight out of the box, without the need for jQuery**

It is loaded on most pages (check in F12 developer tools)
if not, use:

```
EnsureScriptFunc('mQuery.js', 'm$', function() {
// DO STUFF
}
```

see

- http://spdevlab.com/2013/07/01/getting-started-with-mquerym-in-sharepoint-2013-and-sharepoint-online/
- http://netwovenblogs.com/2012/08/20/mquery-for-sharepoint-2013/

Note that with not too complex JavaScript; 
jQuery "magic" can be done without jQuery;
http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ is a very good read